# angular 4 compile failed for awesome-typescript-loader

Tags: typescript, angular

I updated my current angular 2 project to angular 4, and now, got these errors:

```
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exclude' of undefined
at applyDefaults (/Users/frankhe/jnpr_csc/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/src/instance.ts:266:72)
```

package json is:

```
 "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
        "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1
    "angular2-load-children-loader": "^0.1.3",
        "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
"typescript": "^2.0.3",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
        "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "es6-promise-loader": "^1.0.1",
```

and my tsconfig is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Any idea why compile failed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a dependency issue with certain versions of Typescript and Awesome-Typescript-Loader. It should be working with

```
"typescript": "^2.1.4" 
"awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.9"
```

try updating your dependencies for typescript / ATL

more info: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/190

Comment: Thanks. But now I have met another issue: ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/components/datatable.component.d.ts:414:16 
    TS2314: Generic type 'IterableDiffer<V>' requires 1 type argument(s). So I want to exclude node_modules, but when I add "node_modules" to excludes of tsconfig, this directory can not be ignored. any idea?

Comment: @user3006967 sounds like some dependencies are out of date. You won't be able to exclude node_modules because the folder is used to compile your typescript. Make sure your ngx-database is updated to the latest version

Comment: Additionally, if you find you're encountering more errors, you might need to downgrade typescript to `2.0.10` and see where that takes you. Those two packages can be finicky together